# Gay and straight are to sexual orientation as transgender and cisgender are to ______?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, sexual-minorities

> *Gay and straight are to sexual orientation as transgender and cisgender are to ______*

What word would fit best in the blank here? Some options that don’t quite seem to fit:

- **Gender orientation**: Doesn't seem to have widespread adoption or a well-defined meaning.
- **Gender identity**: It would seem more appropriate to say something like “my gender identity is female” rather than “my gender identity is cisgender”. The categories don’t align.
- **Gender expression**: This refers only to the outwardly visible aspects of gender, not to how a person actually identifies.

Comment: Answers go in the answer-box. Please do not answer in comments. Also, comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119729/discussion-on-question-by-lionel-rowe-gay-and-straight-are-to-sexual-orientation).

Answer (score 2):

*Gender identity* is the best phrase here. While you’re right that it’s sometimes used interchangeably with *gender*, it’s also often used as a category label for cis/transgender (and sometimes, in addition, including gender itself), like in the following examples:

> ‘cis’ means cis-gender, meaning the gender you identify as matches the sex you were assigned at birth i.e. I was born female and identify as a female, therefore my gender identity is cis-female. — [Identity: definitions and a guide to.](https://thoughtsoflorelei.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/identity-definitions-and-a-guide-to/)

> I’m a queer cis woman. Queer is my orientation, I am a lesbian woman attracted to other women. My gender identity is cis, which means that I identity as the gender I was assigned at birth. — [UU Studio](https://uustudiocity.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/WCC-11.17.pdf)

> This group is also for teens whose gender identity is cis-gender, transgender, non-binary, gender neutral, gender queer, or those questioning their gender identity.  — [Harmony Center](https://www.harmonycenterforholisticpsychotherapy.com/spectrum-of-rockford-l.g.b.t.-counseling-program.html)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the examples! I guess my conceptualization of this term is too rigid for how it's actually used in real life.

Answer (score 1):

By far, **"gender identity"** seems to be the best choice.

> Gender identity is the personal sense of one's own gender.  Gender identity can correlate with a person's assigned sex at birth or can differ from it. Gender expression typically reflects a person's gender identity, but this is not always the case. While a person may express behaviors, attitudes, and appearances consistent with a particular gender role, such expression may not necessarily reflect their gender identity. The term gender identity was originally coined by Robert J. Stoller in 1964. All societies have a set of gender categories that can serve as the basis of a person's self-identity in relation to other members of society. In most societies, there is a basic division between gender attributes assigned to males and females, a gender binary to which most people adhere and which includes expectations of masculinity and femininity in all aspects of sex and gender: biological sex, gender identity, and gender expression. Some people do not identify with some, or all, of the aspects of gender assigned to their biological sex; some of those people are transgender, non-binary, or genderqueer. Some societies have third gender categories.
> **Gender identity is usually formed by age three. After age three, it is extremely difficult to change gender identity.** Both biological and social factors have been suggested to influence its formation. [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity)